# Count specific datatable columns

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

How to count datatable columns (created dynamically) that has the same first two characters in the header? Here's my code so far but is not working.

```
    For col As Integer = 3 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim cntLE, cntUE As Integer
        If dt.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2) = "LE" Then
            cntLE = dt.Columns.Count
        ElseIf dt.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2) = "UE" Then
            cntUE = dt.Columns.Count
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: See my answer below. Also, why are you starting at `3`, instead of at `0` in the `For` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are assigning the entire column count (i.e. `dt.Columns.Count` ) to the counters, instead of increment them by 1 if found.

Try this.

```
For col As Integer = 3 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
    Dim cntLE, cntUE As Integer
    If dt.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2) = "LE" Then
        cntLE = cntLE + 1
    ElseIf dt.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2) = "UE" Then
        cntUE = cntUE + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ah..  I see :) Thank you. Columns index 0 to 2 are static columns, only Column(3) up are created dynamically that's why the loop starts on 3.